# ActiveRecord: Getting Related Array of Objects From Array of Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models which look like such:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :weapon
end

class Weapon < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to: character
end
```

Given a list of `Character` entities, is there a way that I can quickly pull a list of `Weapon` entities.

In SQL what I would like to  do is

```
SELECT * FROM Characters as c
     INNER JOIN WEAPONS as w
     ON c.id = w.character_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little bit unclear, because I don't know if you're asking for all `Weapon` instances joined to all `Character` records, or for just a subset.

### All `Character` instances joined to all associated `Weapon` instances

```
Weapon.joins(:character).all
```

With this, you will get a `character` property on every instance of `Weapon`. Actually, you don't even need the `joins()` as you can access them directly, which will trigger a `LIMIT ONE`-style SQL query to fetch that record.

### Only for a subset

```
Weapon.joins(:character).all.where(character: characters)
```

This will give you all instances of `Weapon` that have at least one instance of the `characters` array associated with them.

Comment: Is there a way that I can get a `CharacterWeapon` object? (Hence the `select *`)

Comment: You would have to define a junction table first. It doesn't look like you have a `CharacterWeapon` model defined yet. Check out the `has_many_and_belongs_to` docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this : where character_ids is an array of ids

```
Character.eager_load(:weapon)
.where(id: character_ids)
```

Eager_load : act as inner join and select *. you will find a nice summary on the subject via [this link](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/). You can use it to avoid multi-queries between associations.